# Extract elements by name from a nested list

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

For a named, nested list, what is the best way to extract a specific element? If I have a list with known fields (eg, from a yaml file), I want to extract an element (list or otherwise) without having to search through the names and indices or trying to keep track of the levels in the `str` output.

For example, I know that `lm` returns a nested list which contains `qr` info.

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
fit$qr$qraux
# [1] 1.176777 1.046354
```

But if I don't know the order, I just want to specify the list along with the name of the element. Ideally, something would give me both the path of indices to the element *and* path of names to the element *and* the element itself.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016359/how-to-directly-select-the-same-column-from-all-nested-lists-within-a-list), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613880/getting-nested-elements-from-a-list), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890388/r-get-element-by-name-from-a-nested-list)

Comment: see `purrr` package. It is made for that. For linear models, you can also see `broom` package. You will love it.

Comment: Another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890388/r-get-element-by-name-from-a-nested-list

Answer (score 3):

My recursive version 1 started to get more buggy than I first thought, so I took an easy way out and am basically grepping the captured output of `utils:::print.ls_str` (I think).

This has at least two disadvantages so far: captured output and eval-parse-texting, but it seems to work correctly for a very nested list such as in `ggplot2::ggplotGrob`.

These are just some helper functions

```
unname2 <- function(l) {
  ## unname all lists
  ## str(unname2(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)))
  l <- unname(l)
  if (inherits(l, 'list'))
    for (ii in seq_along(l))
      l[[ii]] <- Recall(l[[ii]])
  l
}

lnames <- function(l) {
  ## extract all list names
  ## lnames(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars))
  nn <- lpath(l, TRUE)
  gsub('\\[.*', '', sapply(strsplit(nn, '\\$'), tail, 1))
}

lpath <- function(l, use.names = TRUE) {
  ## return all list elements with path as character string
  ## l <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars); lpath(l); lpath(l, FALSE)
  ln <- deparse(substitute(l))
  # class(l) <- NULL
  l <- rapply(l, unclass, how = 'list')
  L <- capture.output(if (use.names) l else unname2(l))
  L <- L[grep('^\\$|^[[]{2,}', L)]
  paste0(ln, L)
}
```

And this one is returning the useful info

```
lextract <- function(l, what, path.only = FALSE) {
  # stopifnot(what %in% lnames(l))
  ln1 <- eval(substitute(lpath(.l, TRUE), list(.l = substitute(l))))
  ln2 <- eval(substitute(lpath(.l, FALSE), list(.l = substitute(l))))
  cat(ln1[idx <- grep(what, ln1)], sep = '\n')
  cat('\n')
  cat(ln2[idx], sep = '\n')
  cat('\n')
  if (!path.only)
    setNames(lapply(idx, function(x) eval(parse(text = ln1[x]))), ln1[idx])
  else invisible()
}

fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
lextract(fit, 'qraux')
# fit$qr$qraux
# 
# fit[[7]][[2]]
# 
# [1] 1.176777 1.046354
```

So I can use that return value directly or now I have the indices.

```
fit[[7]][[2]]
# [1] 1.176777 1.046354


## etc
lextract(fit, 'qr', TRUE)

# fit$qr
# fit$qr$qr
# fit$qr$qraux
# fit$qr$pivot
# fit$qr$tol
# fit$qr$rank
# 
# fit[[7]]
# fit[[7]][[1]]
# fit[[7]][[2]]
# fit[[7]][[3]]
# fit[[7]][[4]]
# fit[[7]][[5]]
```

I would prefer a built-in or one-liner, however.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another recursive attempt.  I'm not sure exactly about how the output should be structured, but I think this gives the sufficient information to extract the rest.

The return value here is a vector of the indices, and the length of the element.  So, for the `fit` example, it returns `c(inds=7, len=5)`, corresponding to the 7th position in `fit` and the element there is length 5.

```
rnames <- function(lst, item) {
  f <- function(ll, inds) {
    if ((ii <- match(item, names(ll), FALSE)))
      list(inds=c(inds, ii), len=length(ll[[ii]]))
    else if (all(is.atomic(unlist(ll, FALSE))) || !is.list(ll))
      NULL
    else
      lapply(seq_along(ll), function(i) f(ll[[i]], inds=c(inds, i)))
  }
  unlist(f(lst, NULL))
}

rnames(fit, "qr")
# inds  len 
#    7    5
```

This will only find the first matching item, so if a list has multiple elements with the same name, it will return the index of the first match.  A slightly more nested example, where only the first "d" would be returned.

```
lst <- list(
  "a"=list("b"=1, "c"=2, "d"=list(1:5)), 
  "d"=list("f"=5),
  "g"=list("h"=list("i"=1:5), "k"=list(1:3, list(letters[1:4])))
)

rnames(lst, "d")
# inds  len 
#    2    1
```

And, when there are multiple layers of nesting

```
rnames(lst, "k")
# inds1 inds2   len 
#     3     2     2 

## So, that would correspond to 
lst[[3]][[2]][1:2]
```