# Extract values from list of arbitrary depth

Tags: r

I have a messy, highly nested, list:

```
m <- list('form' = list('elements' = list('name' = 'Bob', 'code' = 12), 'name' = 'Mary', 'code' = 15))
```

```
> m
$form
$form$elements
$form$elements$name
[1] "Bob"

$form$elements$code
[1] 12


$form$name
[1] "Mary"

$form$code
[1] 15
```

How can I extract from the object `m` the `name` and `code`, regardless as to how nested `name` and `code` appears within a list?

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name   code
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Bob      12
2 Mary     15
```

Comment: Maybe `x <- unlist(m); data.frame(name=x[endsWith(names(x), "name")], code=x[endsWith(names(x), "code")])`

Comment: Maybe the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044456/extract-elements-by-name-from-a-nested-list) can be of help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) rrapply** Flatten `m` using `rrapply` giving `r` and then separate the name and code fields of `unlist(r)` using `tapply`, remove the dimensions using `c`, convert to data.frame and set the order of the columns.

Note that this is not hard coded to name and code and would work with other fields and numbers of fields.

```
library(rrapply)

r <- rrapply(m, f = c, how = "flatten")
nms <- names(r)
as.data.frame(c(tapply(unname(r), nms, unlist)))[unique(nms)]
```

giving:

```
  name code
1  Bob   12
2 Mary   15
```

An alternative to the final two lines of code above would be:

```
out <- unstack(stack(r))
out[] <- lapply(out, type.convert)
```

If there could be other fields in `m` in addition to `name` and `code` that we want ignored then use this in place of the statement that defines `r` above:

```
cond <- function(x, .xname) .xname %in% c("name", "code")
r <- rrapply(m, cond, c, how = "flatten")
```

**2) Base R** A base R solution is the following which unlists `m`, and then uses `tapply` as in (1) grouping by the suffixes of `names(r)`.  Like (1) this is a general approach that is not hard coded to `name` and `code`.  Note that tools comes with R so it is part of Base R.

```
r <- unlist(m)
nms <- tools::file.ext(names(r))
as.data.frame(c(tapply(unname(r), nms, unlist)))[unique(nms)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help formating the list into a dataframe and then reshaping it:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Process
y1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(m,unlist),stringsAsFactors = F)
y1$id <- rownames(y1)
rownames(y1)<-NULL
#Dplyr mutation
y1 %>% mutate(Var=ifelse(grepl('name',id,),'name',
                         ifelse(grepl('code',id),'code',NA))) %>%
  select(-id) %>% group_by(Var) %>%
  mutate(i=1:n())%>% pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from = form) %>%
  select(-i) %>% mutate(code=as.numeric(code))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name   code
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Bob      12
2 Mary     15
```