dribble (drive google tibble) extract list component (from deep level)
surely this kind of question has been asked a thousand times!
but I just can't find an answer!
i am using googledrive
to manage images of a survey.
it is convenient: with the library "googledrive" i get all drive_resources in one column, but in the form of a nested list.
Here an example simplified
structure(list(name = c("P100_0140.jpeg", "P100_0139.jpeg", "P100_0138.jpeg", 
"P100_0137.jpeg"), id = structure(c("1fzTKlfUrBZrzjARe1M5I9CAm6y4E-Uxe", 
"102B5za7cLmFRc0WpU-DafMFmj-KxFfiS", "1wdfnF1P1lxMT0DHPeSJ1ffhH79nrQIVf", 
"1p_O4Az_FzFAbesiOqRKzQVbZQHZvbmPT"), class = c("drive_id", "vctrs_vctr", 
"character")), drive_resource = list(list(kind = "drive#file", 
    fileExtension = "jpeg", copyRequiresWriterPermission = FALSE, 
    md5Checksum = "01295e31d55ec19cd293e60eaa68ddd3", writersCanShare = TRUE, 
    viewedByMe = TRUE, mimeType = "image/jpeg", parents = list(
        "1Y6qHgsGXXoqYFWQvkT6g75T1UpaVLyAy"), thumbnailLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-storage/AJQWtBOV7Pvgn7P4GtbCUgHW592yC3ctDGOShNFudjd_EIjCjIgey2XvxTY3WL8Xk0_a0FOnkyM8ZgPupKqOh1jqy6bKJ52wj5lG-TGukb1MqeMYlQ=s220", 
    iconLink = "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/jpeg", 
    shared = FALSE, lastModifyingUser = list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
        kind = "drive#user", me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", 
        emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64"), 
    owners = list(list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", kind = "drive#user", 
        me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", 
        photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64")), 
    headRevisionId = "0B0JOUo-YU2H6aFZ2S2k2b2owd25uWjJvejlMd3JVdDJFUkJrPQ", 
    webViewLink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fzTKlfUrBZrzjARe1M5I9CAm6y4E-Uxe/view?usp=drivesdk", 
    webContentLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1fzTKlfUrBZrzjARe1M5I9CAm6y4E-Uxe&export=download", 
    size = "300509", viewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, permissions = list(
        list(id = "00783565146898879905", displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
            type = "user", kind = "drive#permission", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64", 
            emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", role = "owner", 
            deleted = FALSE, pendingOwner = FALSE)), hasThumbnail = TRUE, 
    spaces = list("drive"), id = "1fzTKlfUrBZrzjARe1M5I9CAm6y4E-Uxe", 
    name = "P100_0140.jpeg", starred = FALSE, trashed = FALSE, 
    explicitlyTrashed = FALSE, createdTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:59.331Z", 
    modifiedTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:59.331Z", modifiedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:59.331Z", 
    viewedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:59.331Z", quotaBytesUsed = "300509", 
    version = "2", originalFilename = "P100_0140.jpeg", ownedByMe = TRUE, 
    fullFileExtension = "jpeg", isAppAuthorized = FALSE, capabilities = list(
        canChangeViewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, canEdit = TRUE, 
        canCopy = TRUE, canComment = TRUE, canAddChildren = FALSE, 
        canDelete = TRUE, canDownload = TRUE, canListChildren = FALSE, 
        canRemoveChildren = FALSE, canRename = TRUE, canTrash = TRUE, 
        canReadRevisions = TRUE, canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission = TRUE, 
        canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive = TRUE, canUntrash = TRUE, canModifyContent = TRUE, 
        canMoveItemOutOfDrive = TRUE, canAddMyDriveParent = FALSE, 
        canRemoveMyDriveParent = TRUE, canMoveItemWithinDrive = TRUE, 
        canShare = TRUE, canMoveChildrenWithinDrive = FALSE, 
        canModifyContentRestriction = TRUE, canChangeSecurityUpdateEnabled = FALSE, 
        canAcceptOwnership = FALSE, canReadLabels = FALSE, canModifyLabels = FALSE, 
        canModifyEditorContentRestriction = TRUE, canModifyOwnerContentRestriction = TRUE, 
        canRemoveContentRestriction = FALSE), thumbnailVersion = "1", 
    modifiedByMe = TRUE, permissionIds = list("00783565146898879905"), 
    imageMediaMetadata = list(flashUsed = FALSE, meteringMode = "Pattern", 
        exposureMode = "Auto", colorSpace = "sRGB", whiteBalance = "Auto", 
        width = 1024L, height = 768L, location = list(latitude = 44.5055783333333, 
            longitude = 11.25568, altitude = 0L), rotation = 0L, 
        time = "2022:08:05 08:51:43", cameraMake = "OLYMPUS IMAGING CORP.  ", 
        cameraModel = "TG-3            ", exposureTime = 0.00625, 
        aperture = 6.3, focalLength = 16.48, isoSpeed = 800L, 
        exposureBias = 0L, maxApertureValue = 3L), linkShareMetadata = list(
        securityUpdateEligible = FALSE, securityUpdateEnabled = TRUE), 
    sha1Checksum = "5d5efdad0e9e8c352ffda6796da46c6b11a0187f", 
    sha256Checksum = "4f9f95baf623bf3b21f16e110afccede656c578e778cf699f01461ec3fad33ee"), 
    list(kind = "drive#file", fileExtension = "jpeg", copyRequiresWriterPermission = FALSE, 
        md5Checksum = "b861183bcec16b6e0d628b2a4de2e751", writersCanShare = TRUE, 
        viewedByMe = TRUE, mimeType = "image/jpeg", parents = list(
            "1Y6qHgsGXXoqYFWQvkT6g75T1UpaVLyAy"), thumbnailLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-storage/AJQWtBNx-sci5kGai7lR9CKG1IkylkmIEF6BQ8fMcMlKKNO5bZWV1QJpqellS0LIRzll-2GnXP-FK6POoAsTsXwagS0xtxXi2osf59CzDsIsEFsblQ=s220", 
        iconLink = "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/jpeg", 
        shared = FALSE, lastModifyingUser = list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
            kind = "drive#user", me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", 
            emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64"), 
        owners = list(list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
            kind = "drive#user", me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", 
            emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64")), 
        headRevisionId = "0B0JOUo-YU2H6QVVrSnlnd1gwdmsxTlU5L1lDd3RHYSt1VkQwPQ", 
        webViewLink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/102B5za7cLmFRc0WpU-DafMFmj-KxFfiS/view?usp=drivesdk", 
        webContentLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=102B5za7cLmFRc0WpU-DafMFmj-KxFfiS&export=download", 
        size = "389369", viewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, permissions = list(
            list(id = "00783565146898879905", displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
                type = "user", kind = "drive#permission", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64", 
                emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", 
                role = "owner", deleted = FALSE, pendingOwner = FALSE)), 
        hasThumbnail = TRUE, spaces = list("drive"), id = "102B5za7cLmFRc0WpU-DafMFmj-KxFfiS", 
        name = "P100_0139.jpeg", starred = FALSE, trashed = FALSE, 
        explicitlyTrashed = FALSE, createdTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:56.040Z", 
        modifiedTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:56.040Z", modifiedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:56.040Z", 
        viewedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:56.040Z", quotaBytesUsed = "389369", 
        version = "2", originalFilename = "P100_0139.jpeg", ownedByMe = TRUE, 
        fullFileExtension = "jpeg", isAppAuthorized = FALSE, 
        capabilities = list(canChangeViewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, 
            canEdit = TRUE, canCopy = TRUE, canComment = TRUE, 
            canAddChildren = FALSE, canDelete = TRUE, canDownload = TRUE, 
            canListChildren = FALSE, canRemoveChildren = FALSE, 
            canRename = TRUE, canTrash = TRUE, canReadRevisions = TRUE, 
            canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission = TRUE, canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive = TRUE, 
            canUntrash = TRUE, canModifyContent = TRUE, canMoveItemOutOfDrive = TRUE, 
            canAddMyDriveParent = FALSE, canRemoveMyDriveParent = TRUE, 
            canMoveItemWithinDrive = TRUE, canShare = TRUE, canMoveChildrenWithinDrive = FALSE, 
            canModifyContentRestriction = TRUE, canChangeSecurityUpdateEnabled = FALSE, 
            canAcceptOwnership = FALSE, canReadLabels = FALSE, 
            canModifyLabels = FALSE, canModifyEditorContentRestriction = TRUE, 
            canModifyOwnerContentRestriction = TRUE, canRemoveContentRestriction = FALSE), 
        thumbnailVersion = "1", modifiedByMe = TRUE, permissionIds = list(
            "00783565146898879905"), imageMediaMetadata = list(
            flashUsed = FALSE, meteringMode = "Pattern", exposureMode = "Auto", 
            colorSpace = "sRGB", whiteBalance = "Auto", width = 1024L, 
            height = 768L, location = list(latitude = 44.5053133333333, 
                longitude = 11.255925, altitude = 0L), rotation = 0L, 
            time = "2022:08:05 08:51:03", cameraMake = "OLYMPUS IMAGING CORP.  ", 
            cameraModel = "TG-3            ", exposureTime = 0.003125, 
            aperture = 6.3, focalLength = 16.48, isoSpeed = 800L, 
            exposureBias = 0L, maxApertureValue = 3L), linkShareMetadata = list(
            securityUpdateEligible = FALSE, securityUpdateEnabled = TRUE), 
        sha1Checksum = "32a65c02f088e020e842fe1abe46fd67c7de14cd", 
        sha256Checksum = "b79a96597454d28f122566e19a8ec5579450857de15aa1e837c5393e9a9726a7"), 
    list(kind = "drive#file", fileExtension = "jpeg", copyRequiresWriterPermission = FALSE, 
        md5Checksum = "80f712e2f0edadea84c261a8bc2262ff", writersCanShare = TRUE, 
        viewedByMe = TRUE, mimeType = "image/jpeg", parents = list(
            "1Y6qHgsGXXoqYFWQvkT6g75T1UpaVLyAy"), thumbnailLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-storage/AJQWtBNNPSke_h129jMFtsw-Cu8jZY5Owt8OVd4ouWf-js2SikBseAEK7nGD4EaCygAE1cpr9HjaLK4wjE07O1ZvC77lx03naWNsZp0iY8jFENQKZA=s220", 
        iconLink = "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/jpeg", 
        shared = FALSE, lastModifyingUser = list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
            kind = "drive#user", me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", 
            emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64"), 
        owners = list(list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
            kind = "drive#user", me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", 
            emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64")), 
        headRevisionId = "0B0JOUo-YU2H6Myt1aGJzUnA2TnB2ZlhoNUJyeUU5Qk1YV3VzPQ", 
        webViewLink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wdfnF1P1lxMT0DHPeSJ1ffhH79nrQIVf/view?usp=drivesdk", 
        webContentLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1wdfnF1P1lxMT0DHPeSJ1ffhH79nrQIVf&export=download", 
        size = "364854", viewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, permissions = list(
            list(id = "00783565146898879905", displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
                type = "user", kind = "drive#permission", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64", 
                emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", 
                role = "owner", deleted = FALSE, pendingOwner = FALSE)), 
        hasThumbnail = TRUE, spaces = list("drive"), id = "1wdfnF1P1lxMT0DHPeSJ1ffhH79nrQIVf", 
        name = "P100_0138.jpeg", starred = FALSE, trashed = FALSE, 
        explicitlyTrashed = FALSE, createdTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:52.803Z", 
        modifiedTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:52.803Z", modifiedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:52.803Z", 
        viewedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:52.803Z", quotaBytesUsed = "364854", 
        version = "2", originalFilename = "P100_0138.jpeg", ownedByMe = TRUE, 
        fullFileExtension = "jpeg", isAppAuthorized = FALSE, 
        capabilities = list(canChangeViewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, 
            canEdit = TRUE, canCopy = TRUE, canComment = TRUE, 
            canAddChildren = FALSE, canDelete = TRUE, canDownload = TRUE, 
            canListChildren = FALSE, canRemoveChildren = FALSE, 
            canRename = TRUE, canTrash = TRUE, canReadRevisions = TRUE, 
            canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission = TRUE, canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive = TRUE, 
            canUntrash = TRUE, canModifyContent = TRUE, canMoveItemOutOfDrive = TRUE, 
            canAddMyDriveParent = FALSE, canRemoveMyDriveParent = TRUE, 
            canMoveItemWithinDrive = TRUE, canShare = TRUE, canMoveChildrenWithinDrive = FALSE, 
            canModifyContentRestriction = TRUE, canChangeSecurityUpdateEnabled = FALSE, 
            canAcceptOwnership = FALSE, canReadLabels = FALSE, 
            canModifyLabels = FALSE, canModifyEditorContentRestriction = TRUE, 
            canModifyOwnerContentRestriction = TRUE, canRemoveContentRestriction = FALSE), 
        thumbnailVersion = "1", modifiedByMe = TRUE, permissionIds = list(
            "00783565146898879905"), imageMediaMetadata = list(
            flashUsed = FALSE, meteringMode = "Pattern", exposureMode = "Auto", 
            colorSpace = "sRGB", whiteBalance = "Auto", width = 1024L, 
            height = 768L, location = list(latitude = 44.5055316666667, 
                longitude = 11.255985, altitude = 0L), rotation = 0L, 
            time = "2022:08:05 08:39:58", cameraMake = "OLYMPUS IMAGING CORP.  ", 
            cameraModel = "TG-3            ", exposureTime = 0.0125, 
            aperture = 5.6, focalLength = 14.41, isoSpeed = 800L, 
            exposureBias = 0L, maxApertureValue = 3L), linkShareMetadata = list(
            securityUpdateEligible = FALSE, securityUpdateEnabled = TRUE), 
        sha1Checksum = "b188d98b0475f081bcd77517883b4b1f4a2d0935", 
        sha256Checksum = "3bd90d699c1b396651602a9898e011b2d241067af149d8cdf31e3715244ddc83"), 
    list(kind = "drive#file", fileExtension = "jpeg", copyRequiresWriterPermission = FALSE, 
        md5Checksum = "ad0596aa1e5d188246832344b3d7690b", writersCanShare = TRUE, 
        viewedByMe = TRUE, mimeType = "image/jpeg", parents = list(
            "1Y6qHgsGXXoqYFWQvkT6g75T1UpaVLyAy"), thumbnailLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-storage/AJQWtBM5p7t-knSNv71xUwmlKHfGAfUQ0RH0-q6eSk1crwDBSlnYE9MKRA8Mf8hDDlfJNipBAA1oX0LZhrx0oJEduwYhJJLqTBubl3JV25r16csjOQ=s220", 
        iconLink = "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/image/jpeg", 
        shared = FALSE, lastModifyingUser = list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
            kind = "drive#user", me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", 
            emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64"), 
        owners = list(list(displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
            kind = "drive#user", me = TRUE, permissionId = "00783565146898879905", 
            emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64")), 
        headRevisionId = "0B0JOUo-YU2H6aitPcHdvVE1yNmJnd3MrVFEyYURTOHMxU2ZJPQ", 
        webViewLink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p_O4Az_FzFAbesiOqRKzQVbZQHZvbmPT/view?usp=drivesdk", 
        webContentLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1p_O4Az_FzFAbesiOqRKzQVbZQHZvbmPT&export=download", 
        size = "352048", viewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, permissions = list(
            list(id = "00783565146898879905", displayName = "farm-agroecologia", 
                type = "user", kind = "drive#permission", photoLink = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocIKwkMZ9WIi3DxOaZ_Nk5EOGmW16zC4j2wS4ADuyQm5LEkpPw=s64", 
                emailAddress = "farm.agroecologia@gmail.com", 
                role = "owner", deleted = FALSE, pendingOwner = FALSE)), 
        hasThumbnail = TRUE, spaces = list("drive"), id = "1p_O4Az_FzFAbesiOqRKzQVbZQHZvbmPT", 
        name = "P100_0137.jpeg", starred = FALSE, trashed = FALSE, 
        explicitlyTrashed = FALSE, createdTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:49.421Z", 
        modifiedTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:49.421Z", modifiedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:49.421Z", 
        viewedByMeTime = "2024-05-13T07:35:49.421Z", quotaBytesUsed = "352048", 
        version = "2", originalFilename = "P100_0137.jpeg", ownedByMe = TRUE, 
        fullFileExtension = "jpeg", isAppAuthorized = FALSE, 
        capabilities = list(canChangeViewersCanCopyContent = TRUE, 
            canEdit = TRUE, canCopy = TRUE, canComment = TRUE, 
            canAddChildren = FALSE, canDelete = TRUE, canDownload = TRUE, 
            canListChildren = FALSE, canRemoveChildren = FALSE, 
            canRename = TRUE, canTrash = TRUE, canReadRevisions = TRUE, 
            canChangeCopyRequiresWriterPermission = TRUE, canMoveItemIntoTeamDrive = TRUE, 
            canUntrash = TRUE, canModifyContent = TRUE, canMoveItemOutOfDrive = TRUE, 
            canAddMyDriveParent = FALSE, canRemoveMyDriveParent = TRUE, 
            canMoveItemWithinDrive = TRUE, canShare = TRUE, canMoveChildrenWithinDrive = FALSE, 
            canModifyContentRestriction = TRUE, canChangeSecurityUpdateEnabled = FALSE, 
            canAcceptOwnership = FALSE, canReadLabels = FALSE, 
            canModifyLabels = FALSE, canModifyEditorContentRestriction = TRUE, 
            canModifyOwnerContentRestriction = TRUE, canRemoveContentRestriction = FALSE), 
        thumbnailVersion = "1", modifiedByMe = TRUE, permissionIds = list(
            "00783565146898879905"), imageMediaMetadata = list(
            flashUsed = FALSE, meteringMode = "Pattern", exposureMode = "Auto", 
            colorSpace = "sRGB", whiteBalance = "Auto", width = 1024L, 
            height = 768L, location = list(latitude = 44.5055316666667, 
                longitude = 11.255985, altitude = 0L), rotation = 0L, 
            time = "2022:08:05 08:39:40", cameraMake = "OLYMPUS IMAGING CORP.  ", 
            cameraModel = "TG-3            ", exposureTime = 0.01, 
            aperture = 5.6, focalLength = 14.41, isoSpeed = 800L, 
            exposureBias = 0L, maxApertureValue = 3L), linkShareMetadata = list(
            securityUpdateEligible = FALSE, securityUpdateEnabled = TRUE), 
        sha1Checksum = "05d6cded20419f7e278f23392c360b907d353e04", 
        sha256Checksum = "1b13ac6f3d32ae1bb0a231e860e0854a91152371a97e9182e0a2867972dfce5c"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("dribble", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))                        

Now I only need a few pieces of information
namely thumbnailLink , time the photo was taken, and location, latitude and longitude information
I have found the easiest and most straightforward tool to put the extracted information into a new column
tidyr::hoist
and actually thumbnailLink which is at the first level of the nested lists with this code
drive_day = drive_day %>% hoist(drive_resource, "thumbnailLink",.remove = TRUE)
is extracted without any problems
The problem comes with the other components, which are at a lower level.
How do I work on "imageMediaMetadata" to extract "time" and even further down to extract latitude and longitude from "location"?
Result as:


Your structure is not a valid R object - the parentheses do not match. Also, what is your desired output?

Also - is this question different from Extract values from list of arbitrary depth?

I re-post the structure (entire). rrapply from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472386/extract-values-from-list-of-arbitrary-depth is interesting but I have a tibble with a column with nested ists. Thank you!!

Using grep on unlisted drive_resource to pull out the desired data
unlisted <- unlist(df$drive_resource)

transform(df, 
  time = unlisted[grep("time", names(unlisted))],
  lat = unlisted[grep("latitude", names(unlisted))],
  long = unlisted[grep("longitude", names(unlisted))],
  drive_resource = NULL)
            name                                id                time
1 P100_0140.jpeg 1fzTKlfUrBZrzjARe1M5I9CAm6y4E-Uxe 2022:08:05 08:51:43
2 P100_0139.jpeg 102B5za7cLmFRc0WpU-DafMFmj-KxFfiS 2022:08:05 08:51:03
3 P100_0138.jpeg 1wdfnF1P1lxMT0DHPeSJ1ffhH79nrQIVf 2022:08:05 08:39:58
4 P100_0137.jpeg 1p_O4Az_FzFAbesiOqRKzQVbZQHZvbmPT 2022:08:05 08:39:40
               lat      long
1 44.5055783333333  11.25568
2 44.5053133333333 11.255925
3 44.5055316666667 11.255985
4 44.5055316666667 11.255985

