# extracting data from deeply nested list

Tags: r, purrr

Consider this convoluted and nested example (which, believe it or not arises for real in my dataset)

```
> nestedlist <- list(list('fakedata' = 'hello',
+                    list(list('name'= list('john','litz'), 'age'= 30))),
+                    list('fakedata' = 'there',
+                    list(list('name'= list('frank','doe'), 'age'= 34))))
> 
> nestedlist %>% str
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ fakedata: chr "hello"
  ..$         :List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ name:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "john"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "litz"
  .. .. ..$ age : num 30
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ fakedata: chr "there"
  ..$         :List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ name:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "frank"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "doe"
  .. .. ..$ age : num 34
```

I am trying to use `purrr` to extract elements from it. Something simple like extracting the `fakedata` field works easily:

```
> purrr::map(nestedlist, 'fakedata')
[[1]]
[1] "hello"

[[2]]
[1] "there"
```

However, I am interested in the `name` field. And in this case my `purrr` solution does not work:

```
> purrr::map(nestedlist, list(1,1,'name')) 
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

What is the issue here?
Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to extract "name" without knowing the structure of the list? ie, wherever you find "name," return it? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044456/extract-elements-by-name-from-a-nested-list) is years old but sounds similar

Comment: I think the issue is that one of the nested lists is not named...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest the use of `purrr::pluck()`, then then reading through the doco I discovered you could actually just use a `purrr::map()`.

You're very close: you need to pass a list of accessors to `map()` rather than a character vector, and there's an accessor you've missed.

```
nestedlist %>% map( list('data', 1, 'name') )

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "john"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "litz"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "frank"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "doe"
```

Comment: if youre going to do this, why use a package at all? `lapply(nestedlist, function(x) x[['data']][[1]][['name']])`

Comment: actually, the solution does not work if the list is not named (which is the case in my data). I have updated the example. sorry about that. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package (an extension of base `rapply()`), which is made exactly for this purpose:

```r
library(rrapply)   ## v1.2.1

## filter 'name' nodes as flat list
str(rrapply(nestedlist, classes = "list", condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "name", how = "flatten"))
#> List of 2
#>  $ name:List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "john"
#>   ..$ : chr "litz"
#>  $ name:List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr "frank"
#>   ..$ : chr "doe"


## prune 'name' nodes maintaining list structure
str(rrapply(nestedlist, classes = "list", condition = function(x, .xname) .xname == "name", how = "prune"))
#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ name:List of 2
#>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "john"
#>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "litz"
#>  $ :List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ name:List of 2
#>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "frank"
#>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "doe"
```